# CUDA в visual studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, компиляция, cuda

Установил CUDA в вижуале, хочу написать первую пробную программу

```
func <<<1,SIZE>>>(work, sym, a);
```

ругается на угловые скобочки, что нужно изменить в свойствах проекта?

Comment: Какая версия cuda?

Comment: Последняя, девятая. Кстати после десятого запуска он начал опускать ошибки. Не могу сказать что проблема решена. Так как он тут же закрывает только что открытый поток